# File not found Error in reading text in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a text file on my hard drive via python with the following script:

```
fileref = open("H:\CloudandBigData\finalproj\BeautifulSoup\twitter.txt","r")
```

But it is giving the following error:

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4f422ec273ce> in <module>()
----> 1 fileref = open("H:\CloudandBigData\finalproj\BeautifulSoup\twitter.txt","r")

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\CloudandBigData\x0cinalproj\\BeautifulSoup\twitter.txt'
```

I also tried with other way:

```
with open('H:\CloudandBigData\finalproj\BeautifulSoup\twitter.txt', 'r') as f:
    print f.read()
```

Ended up with the same error. The text file is present in the directory specified.

Comment: Escape your backslashes properly

Comment: Use a raw string (`r"..."`) instead.  The backslashes are causing you problems.  For example, `"\f" == "\x0c"`.  Even better, use forward slashes - Windows doesn't care.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.How to Escape properly?  Do you want me to write the file path manually, because I just copy pasted the path.

Comment: Change each backslash to two backslashes, **or** use a raw string, **or** use forward slashes instead.

Comment: @TimPeters **or** use `os.path.join` as in my answer... that really removes the possibility of problems like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
fileref = open("H:\CloudandBigData\finalproj\BeautifulSoup\twitter.txt","r")
```

with

```
fileref = open(r"H:\CloudandBigData\finalproj\BeautifulSoup\twitter.txt","r")
```

Here, I have created a raw string (`r""`).  This will cause things like `"\t"` to not be interpreted as a tab character.

Another way to do it without a raw string is

```
fileref = open("H:\\CloudandBigData\\finalproj\\BeautifulSoup\\twitter.txt","r")
```

This escapes the backslashes (i.e. `"\\" => \`).

---

An **even better** solution is to use the `os` module:

```
import os
filepath = os.path.join('H:', 'CloudandBigData', 'finalproj', 'BeautifulSoup', 'twitter.txt')
fileref = open(filepath, 'r')
```

This creates your path in an os-independent way so you don't have to worry about those things.

---

One last note... in general, I think you should use the `with` construct you mentioned in your question... I didn't in the answer for brevity.

Comment: I am still getting the same error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-efb8327ff8e4> in <module>()
----> 1 fileref = open("H:\\CloudandBigData\\finalproj\\BeautifulSoup\\twitter.txt","r")

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\CloudandBigData\\finalproj\\BeautifulSoup\\twitter.txt'

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-d0833ef16577> in <module>()
----> 1 fileref = open(r"H:\CloudandBigData\finalproj\BeautifulSoup\twitter.txt","r")

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\CloudandBigData\\finalproj\\BeautifulSoup\\twitter.txt'

Comment: Do we need to install any libraries in python prior to reading a text file?

Comment: If you you are still getting the "No such file or directory", are you sure that the file exists?  And no, you don't need any libraries.

Comment: I would like to point out the error isn't *exactly* the same.  In your question, the name of the file was messed up because of the special characters (specifically `\f` and `\t`.) In the traceback you posted in the above comment, the filename is "correct", so if you are still getting the error it must be because the file does not exist.

Comment: I just realised the mistake. I am running python in Wakari which is running cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering same problem. This problem resulted due to different file path notation Python.
For example, filepath in Windows reads with backward slash like: "D:\Python\Project\file.txt"

But Python reads file path with forward slash like: "D:/Python/Project/file.txt"

I used  r"filepath.txt" and "os.path.join" and "os.path.abspath" to no relief. os library also generates file path in Windows notation. Then I just resorted to IDE notation.

You don't encounter this error if "file.txt" is located in same directory, as filename is appended to working directory.

PS: I am using Python 3.6 with Spyder IDE on Windows machine.